# Can TLSv1.0 ciphers be used with SSLv3?

Tags: tls, cipher-selection

Can TLS cipher, such as TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, suites be used within an SSLv3 connection?

For example, say the client and server both support TLS but the connection is downgraded to an SSLv3 implementation.  Would they be able to negotiate a cipher suite using a cipher defined for TLSv1.0?  Or, what if the client and/or server only supports SSLv3, and has no support for TLSv1.0?

Comment: This question isn't terribly relevant anymore; SSL3 should be disabled due to POODLE, see [Ivan Ristic's 
SSL 3 is dead, killed by the POODLE attack](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2014/10/15/ssl-3-is-dead-killed-by-the-poodle-attack)

Answer (score 2):

> Would they be able to negotiate a cipher suite using a cipher defined for TLSv1.0?

## Yes.

`RFC 7568` *Deprecating Secure Sockets Layer Version 3.0* was just published (2015-06-26).

(The draft to this RFC was affectionately known as `draft-ietf-tls-sslv3-diediedie`.)

Quote from RFC 7568's [Section 5: Limited Capabilities](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568#section-5):

> Though SSLv3 can benefit from new cipher suites, it cannot benefit from new cryptographic modes and features

So, yeah, technically. But I don't know if you'll find any implementation to actually do this.